# Struts 2 Interceptor redirection not working with Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struts2

I have configured Struts 2 Interceptor for validating the user session. On invalid session I am redirecting to an error page.

The Interceptor is working fine for the normal calls to the action classes but the error page redirection is not working when I am calling an action class through ajax call.

What I am currently doing for this is sestting a request attribute in the interceptor and on the JSP based on that attribute value redirecting from the JSP.

But instead of what I am doing is there any way by which I dont need to write any thing in JSP for error page redirection to work in the similar way when calling the action class in a normal way and in the form of Ajax

Thanks,
Vinay

Comment: That should work for Ajax calls also if it is not working you are making some mistakes. Please provide your ajax calling and Interceptor calling... ?

Comment: Define "not working". An Ajax call isn't a normal call; the redirect's results will be returned to the JS making the Ajax call. It's more likely you need to distinguish between normal and Ajax calls and do something with the *JS* response sent back, like set an error condition, etc.

Comment: The interceptor is getting called but the redirection I am setting in the interceptor in case of error is not getting called it is remaining in the same jsp with out showing any thing. Dave Newton, Do you mean that when its ajax call instead of setting parameters in request and returning the return string I need to send the stream as if I am sending to an ajax response right and handle that redirection part from the java script. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the interceptor, set the response status to UnAuthorized just before we return the errorpage.

   ```
          httpResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
          return "errorPage";
   ```
2. In the ajax call where we make a request that ends up in session timeout and redirect, put a error handling block and redirect to the page directly here.

   ```
     $.ajax({
       url : "some.action",
           data : {
               "query" : inputText
       },
       type : 'GET',
       dataType : 'json',
   success : function(data) {
       //code
   },
   error : function(data) {
       if (data.status == 401 ){
           console.log("UnAuthorized. Redirecting to Error");
           window.location.replace(contextPath +"/error.jsp");
       }
   }
   ```
3. Have a struts entry for the errorpage to avoid any config issues.

   ```
       <result name="errorPage">errorPage.jsp</result>
   ```